# Android Advertising ID compatibility

Tags: android, ads

Announcing the Android Advertising ID as "forced" replacement for Android ID, Google did not mention the compatibility concerns.

With iOS, the new advertising identifier was introduced from ~6.0, not downward compatible.

How is this managed with Android now? Do we need a fallback for former Android ID or does each api version support the new identifier? The manual does not cover these concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Requirements
>
> The advertising ID APIs are supported in Google Play services 4.0+
>   Support for the advertising ID on specific devices is based on their installed versions of Google

Play services

From the example provided,

```
public void getIdThread() {

  Info adInfo = null;
  try {
    adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);

  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,
    // the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).
  }
}
```

You need to handle the exception if the user's device is not updated to the required version.

Comment: The exception handler is clear and no worries on this. However, documentation. `Google Play services 4.0+` is a very limited information. Does it also mean that Android OS 4.0+. E.g. there is no statement regarding Android 2.3. We'd need to know whether Play App 4.0 can be installed on a 2.3 OS etc.

Comment: It does support `2.3` and above. According to Google, with the `Play Services 4.0` update, it has dropped support for `2.2`, and devices running `2.3` and above will be supported. However, the problem is that Google is slowly sending out the `Play Services 4.0` updates, and devices that haven't received the update will face problems. That's why the application developer should make sure to handle the exceptions caused due to this.